# how to isolate virtualenv from local dist-packages?

Tags: python, virtualenv

How do you stop virtualenv using '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'?

currently it when i run

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages ENV
```

it still uses the dist-packages that i wish to stop

EDIT: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is in the PYTHONPATH, it needs to be there for other apps

Comment: `virtualenv --no-site-packages` creates an empty virtualenv. Are you sure that you activated the correct virtualenv when checking via `pip freeze` the list of installed packages.

Comment: yes im sure it is the correct env, could it be to do with PYTHONPATH?

Comment: `--no-site-packages` flag is deprecated by the opposite [`--system-site-packages` flag](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#the-system-site-packages-option) in recent `virtualenv` versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your edit explains the behaviour you are observing.

You need to unset `PYTHONPATH` when activating the virtualenv.

```
unset PYTHONPATH
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```

`virtualenv --no-site-packages ENV` creates an empty virtualenv just fine, but your `PYTHONPATH` export nullifies your empty virtualenv.

In order to make things simpler you can just edit the `activate` script and add the `unset PYTHONPATH` command there. If you want to restore the original PYTHONPATH upon deactivating the virtualenv you also need to modify the `deactivate` function in that file.

Comment: so if i unset the pythonpath i pressume that will affect more than just that enviroment? is it possible to unset then reset?

Comment: Environment variables are bound to the shell. `unset PYTHONPATH` will only modify the environment variable for the currently running shell. If you do not want to modify your current shell just start another shell inside your current shell.

Comment: Thanks it works, Is there any automately way to solve it? and Is it a issue with virtualenv?